# Implementing the PMod-ALS on the Basys2 Board in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I'm attempting to use the ALS Pmod with the Basys2 board in VHDL.
How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a [3-wire SPI™ communication interface](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,401,1190&Prod=PMOD-ALS).  The Texas Instruments [ADC081S021 Single Channel, 50 to 200 ksps, 8-Bit A/D Converter](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/adc081s021.pdf) (PDF data sheet) is intended to be polled.  Note from the TI datasheet you don't need a full SPI slave interface, it's read only, a simple port. From the schematic for the PMOD-ALS it appears it operates in continuous tracking mode.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'd seen that I had to use an SPI on that PDF, but I didn't see that TI interface.